# Dynamically set Spinner not persisting state

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a simple application and I've ran into persisting the state for a dynamically created `Spinner`. No matter what I choose for the dynamic spinner, it's always reset to the first element defined. I've overriden the `onPause` and `onResume` with no effect. Any help would be great.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private OnItemSelectedListener optionListener = getOptionListener();
// private OnItemSelectedListener specificListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.optionsSpinner)).setOnItemSelectedListener(optionListener);
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    int generalIndex = ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.optionsSpinner)).getSelectedItemPosition();
    int specificIndex = ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.specificOptions)).getSelectedItemPosition();

    prefs.edit().putInt("general", generalIndex).putInt("specific", specificIndex).commit();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    int generalIndex = prefs.getInt("general", -1);
    int specificIndex = prefs.getInt("specific", -1);

    ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.optionsSpinner)).setSelection(generalIndex);
    ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.specificOptions)).setSelection(specificIndex);
}

private OnItemSelectedListener getOptionListener()
{
    return new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {

            int resId;
            String selectedOption = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (selectedOption.equals(getString(R.string.color)))
                resId = R.array.colorsArray;
            else
                resId = R.array.shapesArray;

            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getBaseContext(), resId, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.specificOptions)).setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what to do:
1). Provide two private variables (one for specific index, one for the general index)
2). Set the two variables from the shared preferences
3). In the onItemSelectedListener, set the specific options spinner

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int specificIndex;
private int generalIndex;
private OnItemSelectedListener optionListener = getOptionListener();
// private OnItemSelectedListener specificListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.optionsSpinner)).setOnItemSelectedListener(optionListener);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    // Initial setup
    generalIndex = prefs.getInt("general", 0);
    specificIndex = prefs.getInt("specific", 0);
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    generalIndex = ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.optionsSpinner)).getSelectedItemPosition();
    specificIndex = ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.specificOptions)).getSelectedItemPosition();

    prefs.edit().putInt("general", generalIndex).putInt("specific", specificIndex).commit();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    generalIndex = prefs.getInt("general", 0);
    specificIndex = prefs.getInt("specific", 0);
}

private OnItemSelectedListener getOptionListener()
{
    return new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {

            int resId;
            String selectedOption = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (selectedOption.equals(getString(R.string.color)))
                resId = R.array.colorsArray;
            else
                resId = R.array.shapesArray;

            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getBaseContext(), resId, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.specificOptions)).setAdapter(adapter);

            if (specificIndex != 0)
                ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.specificOptions)).setSelection(specificIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }
    };
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For starters,there is something wrong with preference `Editor`. You need to commit the preferences this:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    int generalIndex = ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.optionsSpinner)).getSelectedItemPosition();
    int specificIndex = ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.specificOptions)).getSelectedItemPosition();

   Editor editor = prefs.edit();
   editor.putInt("general", generalIndex);
   editor.putInt("specific", specificIndex);
   editor.commit();
```

Otherwise your preferences will not be saved.

Another thing I want to point out is you need to avoid `-1` as default preference value and then use `-1` with `.setSelection(value);`, it will cause you exception. Avoid any selection if -1 is returned.

Comment: I understand the -1 bit, but it's just for demonstrating purposes. It actually never gives me -1. On the topic of the sharedpreferences, if you take a look at onPause, I do commit the preferences:  prefs.edit().putInt("general", generalIndex).putInt("specific", specificIndex).commit();